# Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing when calling function

Tags: listings

I'm trying to this:

```
\newcommand{\code}[1] {\begin{lstlisting} {#1} \end{lstlisting} }
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing
```

I'm calling `\usepackage` and all so, do any of you knows how to solve this?

Comment: You can't put verbatim material in the argument to another command and `listings` material is like verbatim.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it? Or do i have to do "manually" for my every piece of code?

Comment: Where's the convenience of `\code{foo}` with respect to `\begin{lstlisting}foo\end{lstlisting}`? Particularly when `foo` is several lines. If you need to get "inline" listings, consider the command `\lstinline`.

Comment: It's more pratic writing it, that's all.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

### Inline Listings:

If you want inline listings you can use `\lstinline{listing content}`. If the content of the listings contains curly braces you could actually use a different character to delimit the start and end as in `\lstinline`listing content with {}`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
To have inline listings use  \lstinline{listing content} to get the formatting.

To have inline listings use  \lstinline`listing content with {}` to get the formatting.
\end{document}
```

---

### Displayed Listings:

For displayed listings, you need to use

```
\begin{lstlisting}
    ... code to be formatted ...
\end{lstlisting}
```

or you can define your own environment via `\lstnewenvironment`.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
For displayed listings use  \verb|\begin{lstlisting} ... \end{lstlisting}|
\begin{lstlisting}
   listing content
\end{lstlisting}
to get the formatting.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

use `listings` own definition for new environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstnewenvironment{code}
  {\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,keywordstyle=\color{blue},
           language=[LaTeX]{TeX},frame=single,backgroundcolor=\color{blue!20}}}
  {}
\begin{document}
\noindent foo
\begin{code}
\lstnewenvironment{code}{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small}
\end{code}
bar
\end{document}
```

[image]