# Define new command which insert environment

Tags: listings, environments

Am i able to do something like this: (without defining new environment)

```
\newcommand{\code}[2] { 
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=#1]
        #2
    \end{lstlisting} 
}
```

I don't want to write:

```
\begin{code}{python}
    >>> print "Hello World!"
\end{code}
```

I want to be able to write:

```
\code{python}{>>> print "Hello World!"}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unfortunately it's not possible. For one liners, as you seem to want, `listings` provides `\lstinline`.

Comment: You can wrap around `\lstinline` *without* reading the argument: `\newcommand*\code[1]{\lstinline[language=#1]}`. As @egreg says this only works for short inline code

Comment: What egreg said. `lstlisting` is like a verbatim environment; it's fragile and can't really be included in the arguments of other commands. This post might help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59715/package-listings-warning-text-dropped-after-begin-of-listing-when-calling-funct It contains some more egreg wisdom, too.  As an aside, try searching the archive before asking a question; you're probably not the first to run into a given problem.